# Optimized RequireJS module file loads, but does nothing

Tags: requirejs, gulp, amd

I'm learning to use [amd-optimize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-optimize) with Gulp and I have a problem where an optimised AMD file loads but doesn't execute. I can see it in the dev tools networks tab, but it does nothing nor give errors.

[image]

I made a test case with single module called pinkyfyer, it changes the body bg to pink. If I load it normally, it works, but after optimisation it does nothing.

My dir structure:

```
dist
└── js
    └── global.js          // The optimized file
src
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── index.html             // Main index file
└── js
    ├── config.js          // RequireJS netry point
    └── modules
        └── pinkifyer.js   // Test module
```

Init RequireJS in `index.html`:

```
<script data-main="js/config" src="lib/require.js"></script>
```

The entry point, `config.js`:

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
    baseUrl: 'js',
    // If I load the app straight without optimisation,
    // the pinkyfyer works
    // deps: ['modules/app'],
    // But the optimised file does nada
    deps: ['../dist/js/global.js']
});
```

And the simply `app.js`:

```
define(function(require) {
    require('./pinkifyer');
});
```

The scripts Gulp task with [amd-optimize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-optimize):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    amdOptimize = require('amd-optimize'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src(['src/js/**/*.js'], { base: 'src/js' })
        // Traces all modules and outputs them in the correct order
        .pipe(amdOptimize('modules/app', {
            baseURL: 'src/js',
            configFile: 'src/js/config.js',
            findNestedDependencies: true
        }))
        .pipe(concat('global.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
});
```

And finally here's the `global.js` that the amd-optimize outputs:

```
define('modules/pinkifyer', [], function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
});
define('modules/app', [
    'require',
    'exports',
    'module',
    'modules/pinkifyer'
], function (require) {
    require('./pinkifyer');
});
```

I tried to change the module names in the `global.js`, but it didn't help.

I'm missing something very elementary here. Thanks advance!

#### Edit

I tried `r.js` and it yielded the following result that works if I load it straight in the `index.html` file `<script data-main="dist/js/global" src="lib/require.js"></script>`:

```
define('modules/pinkifyer',[],function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
});

define('modules/app',['require','./pinkifyer'],function(require) {

    require('./pinkifyer');

});

require.config({
    urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
    baseUrl: 'js',
    deps: ['modules/app']
    // deps: ['../dist/js/global.js']
});

define("config", function(){});
```

It's something I don't get in the amd-optimize plugin.